# dreamweaver css id and class generate

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Is it possible to make Dreamveawer able to create css file with empty #id and .class rules based on html file and written id and classes in this html file?

It will be really useful if I could generate all existing ids and classes from written html.

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right:

Yes, you can declare a #id or .class in your CSS file without any attributes or rules and only set them in the "style" attribute in the HTML file.

No, you CAN'T and WON'T be able to generate a CSS file out of a previously created HTML file with all its IDs and Classes, you would have to do it manually.

Hope this is what you expected to know.